# How to read heap size -- occupied and free?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, heap-memory

I would like to read those 2 values -- how much memory I allocated in total, and how much is free left (visible for JVM, not for OS).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Runtime.totalMemory() and Runtime.freeMemory().

You can see this using VisualVM.

Note: the free memory is the unused memory, not how much memory would be free if the garbage was cleaned.  This means there can be no memory free but there is no problem because as soon as the GC is called there will be.

For this reason its best to look at how much memory is free after a GC.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either VisualVM (or) JConsole tools.

When you run one of these tools, you will pick the java process against which you would like to see the usage.

If you are using MBean you may use `java.lang:type=Memory`

Answer (score 0):

At least on a unix-like system you can [send your program a SIGQUIT](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/v5r0/topic/com.ibm.java.doc.diagnostics.50/diag/tools/javadump_trigger.html) to get a javadump, which has a section about memory.

```
An example from the linked page:
MEMINFO subcomponent dump routine
=================================
Bytes of Heap Space Free: 365df8
Bytes of Heap Space Allocated: 400000
```